# Google Analytics Code Need clarifications

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, analytics

I need SEO help. I want to ask if these scripts number 1 and 2 does the same thing. The number 1 is located in the `<head>` while the number 2 is located just before the `</body>` tag. Because I think these 2 scripts function similarly and skews my website traffic data. Can someone please help enlighten me. Thank you.

1.)

```
<script async src="/wp-content/google/solarwhiz_tracking.js"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-20229862-2');
</script>
```

2.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','gaplusu');

            function gaplus_track() {
            gaplusu('create', 'UA-20229862-2', 'auto');
                                                                                                gaplusu('send', 'pageview');
                                }
                                gaplus_track();
            
        </script>
```

And when I look at the tracking code in our analytics admin, the code is like this

```
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-20229862-2"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-20229862-2');
</script>
```

What if I replaced the number 1.) with this code? will my historical data be erased too?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Historical and processed data will not be erased. Some of the things the JS tags do is preparing the JS code to execute different functions and create the image request tag that goes to the Google Analytics servers. What you have right now are two implementations that both send data to the same property, causing duplications most likely. You'd want to clean that up and only use one code line. BUT - snippets #1 and #3 use Google Tag Manager and snippet #2 is a direct implementation of analytics.js. Please be mindful.

Comment: Thank you @MrSponge. Is the number 1 and 2 snippets causing duplicates on my traffic data?

Comment: Most likely it would, yes. If you remove a tracking code, data will not be erased. It will still be in the account, but it won't collect any new data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just replace the number 1, your data not be erase, if google data analytisc stop tracking you can previos number 1. Trust me, your data will normal